# dual polarity powersupply in this circuit how we connect the battery dc supply?

Tags: power

12-0-12 vac connected to brigde rectifier for +12/-12 dual polarity power supply for amp and sub woofer circuit in this circuit how we connect the battery 12vdc power? and how we can change this dual polarity power suplly connect with 12vdc battery?

Comment: Are you asking how to use +12V DC from a 12V battery to produce +12VDC and -12VDC at the same time?

Comment: Hey Ramesh, this may be what you are asking for http://www.physics.unlv.edu/~bill/PHYS483/power_supply_info.pdf but will not work. There is too much ripple in AC to DC for good sub-woofer so an efficient switching regulator may be better.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with just that one 12 V battery. You can use it for the +12 V, but you still need something for the -12 V. That could be another battery, and then you connect the `+` of the second battery to the `-` of the first.

Depending on the power you need you can also use a switching regulator to create -12 V from +12 V. In that case note that the battery has to supply power for both +12 V and -12 V, so that will half the battery's life.

*Note that 12 V AC rectified will give you 15 V DC, not 12 V.*

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to use a single 12V battery to produce +12VDC and -12VDC at the same time to power an amplifier.

By itself the single battery cannot make both +12V and -12V relative to local "ground" at the same time.

One solution is to use the battery directly to provide eg +12VDC and us a switch mode power supply ("SMPS") to make -12VDC.

The circuit below shows one of the lowest cost ways of doing this.
 This uses the cheap and widely available MC34063 or equivalent plus a few external components. [MC34063 data sheet here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF).    The diagrams below are adapted from page 8 of the data sheet.

As shown the circuit states 100 mA output but using the iCF only up to about 750 mA can be supplied. For more current and power the two circuits at bottom can be used. The bipolar transistors shown can be replaced by MOSFETS with some drive changes. The inductor inductance and current handling must be designed to meet the requirement. There are more efficient devices than this, but this is about as low a cost SMPS design as can be managed.

[image]
c:\zzz\MC34063 inverting.jpg

---

A completely different solution is to have two 12V batteries to give +/0 !2V. These can either be charged in series as a 24V battery or can be connected in parallel as a 12V battery when charging or charged individually. As the two individual batteries require less capacity than a single 12V battery + inverter the cost may be not much dearer than using a single larger 12V battery - so this MAY be the most cost effective solution.